# Apple CNA not showing Facebook Style Sheet (Captive Portal)

Tags: macos, facebook, facebook-graph-api, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I have created a captive portal which requires the user to authenticate via Facebook & Twitter.

When the user connects to the hotspot it produces the Captive Network Assistant (Captive portal window).

Everything to this point works fine, CSS, HTML, JS & PHP loads fine without any issue.

When the user authenticate via Twitter, they are redirected to api.twitter.com and again, no issues here, all of the CSS etc loads perfectly.

However, when the user clicks Facebook it loads as shown below, it looks like the Stylesheet is being blocked for some reason.

I have tried adding all of the assosicated URLS to the walled garden:

```
FirewallRule allow tcp to facebook.com                                 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn.net                                    
FirewallRule allow tcp to akamaihd.net                                 
FirewallRule allow tcp to crl3.digicert.com                            
FirewallRule allow tcp to crl4.digicert.com                            
FirewallRule allow tcp to ocsp.digicert.com                            
FirewallRule allow tcp to cacerts.digicert.com                         
FirewallRule allow tcp to digicert.com                                 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbsbx.com                                    
FirewallRule allow tcp to static.xx.fbcdn.net                          
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net
```

## At this point I was just adding anything I could find linked to FB, regardless of how fruitless it was

```
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net  
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net   
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-i-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-j-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-k-a.akamaihd.net  
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-l-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-m-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-n-a.akamaihd.net 
FirewallRule allow tcp to scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net  
FirewallRule allow tcp to scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net  
FirewallRule allow tcp to fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net   
FirewallRule allow tcp to facebook.net
```

This issue seems to be isolated to OS X only, when clicking the FB link on any Mobile or a windows laptop, there is no issue and it works as expected.

When closing the CNA window and opening the Captive Portal in the web browser (Firefox or Safari) it loads without issue.

So from this, it looks to be linked to OS X CNA.
Doe's anyone have any ideas on what is causing this, a resolution or a workaround?

I do not want to stop using CNA completely.